# HTML5 Canvas cross-domain security issue

Tags: html, security, canvas, cross-domain

What specifically are the security issues that arise by allowing cross-domain image data to be manipulated?

I know that if you have access to both domains you can allow it. I'm wondering why it would be ill-advised to load in Facebook / Instagram images into a canvas to manipulate.

Note that attempting this locally won't work, must run on localhost or on a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the security issue is in manipulation -- it's in reading or capturing a screenshot from another page. A variation of the theme is reading raw pixels from an image, that is intended to be displayed, but not for OCR... (e.g. some bank account secrets.)

http://www.contextis.com/resources/blog/webgl2/

From the start WebGL implementations suffered from non-conformance to specifications, which probably led Microsoft to develop alternative technology on IE and simultaneously claim that providing an access to GPU with a web page is a high risk by itself.

Comment: Good answer, but `canvas != WebGL`.